# US Treasury interest rate swaps

Tags: interest-rate-swap

I know that Bloomberg will give me the swap rates for Treasury 30's-5's, but I don't have a Bloomberg.  Can anyone direct me to a source?

Comment: Federal Reserve Economic Data.

Comment: See for example here https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h15/update/ for current data (under Interest Rate Swaps), or under Historical Data tab for older data.